# Modify a custom styled button's border in WPF XAML

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I'm trying to achieve [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OhLen.jpg) through XAML code but to no avail.

I have the following XAML code:

App.xaml

```
<Style x:Key="ButtonStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Black"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                <Grid>
                    <Path Fill="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                          Data="M 0,22.5 22.5,0 27.5,5 10,22.5 27.5,40 22.5,45"/>
                    <Border x:Name="border"
                            BorderThickness="2"
                            BorderBrush="Red"/>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

And use it like so:

```
<Button Style="{StaticResource ButtonStyle}" Height="100" Width="100"/>
```

It gives me [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HYyyL.jpg) but I want the red border to be inside the button.

I tried adding this

```
<Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Red"/>
<Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="2"/>
```

instead of creating a grid but now the border doesn't show.

I guess I could create another path that would act as a border but is there a simpler way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<Style x:Key="ButtonStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Black"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                <Grid>
                    <Path Fill="{TemplateBinding Background}" Stroke="Red" StrokeThickness="3"
                      Data="M 0,22.5 22.5,0 27.5,5 10,22.5 27.5,40 22.5,45"/>
                    <Border x:Name="border"
                        BorderThickness="2"
                        BorderBrush="Red"/>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

trying to use Stroke and StrokeThickness properties.

Comment: Thank you, it worked.
For some reasons

```<Path Fill="{TemplateBinding Background}" Stroke="RosyBrown" StrokeThickness="2"
         Data="M 0,22.5 22.5,0 27.5,5 10,22.5 27.5,40 22.5,45"/>```
   
produced [this](https://imgur.com/a/WuStJ55), without the bottom line.

I had to change it to 

```<Polygon Points="0,22.5 22.5,0 27.5,5 10,22.5 27.5,40 22.5,45" Fill="Black" Stroke="RosyBrown" StrokeThickness="2"/>```

 for the desired result.